# How to modify Firefox's MimeTypes.rdf with dotNetRDF?

Tags: rdf, dotnetrdf

For each content type Firefox recognizes, you may select an action that Firefox will use to handle that type of content. It stores these actions in a file called [MimeTypes.rdf](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf).

How can I modify this file with C#? How else could I teach Firefox how to handle new MIME types?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to explicitly modify them with C# or dotNetRDF?

Typically you can manually edit them yourself by going to `Preferences > Applications`

I'm not sure you can use dotNetRDF to edit this file because it uses `rdf:Seq` and `rdf:li` which are considered somewhat archaic (though legal syntax).  While you could happily read that file into dotNetRDF I don't believe we support serializing it back out with those syntax constructs so if Firefox is expecting those exact constructs you would render the file unreadable.

Comment: Thank you for your help. To improving user's experience with our product,one user demand is that implement it automation. Our product with c#,and dotNetRDF is a dll for file extensions with RDF.